# Principal Password in Kerberos KDC database

Tags: passwords, kerberos, identification, fingerprint

Is there a way for me to merge a bank account number, fingerprint image and IMEI of a phone into a single entity that I could possibly use as a password in the Kerberos KDC to uniquely identity a Principal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Fingerprint images can be compared with each other, but are not reliably reproducible with all the exactness that is needed for use as a cryptographic key (and passwords are cryptographic keys that just happen to look like characters).